# MS Access: Any Ideas on How to Create an Excel-Like Form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Objective: Convert an overgrown Excel sheet into an Access database, but maintain a front-end that is familiar and easy to use.

There are several aspects to this, but the one I'm stuck on is one of the input forms.  I'm not going to clutter this question with the back-end implementation that I have already tried because I'm open to changing it.  Currently, an Excel spreadsheet is used to input employee hour allocations to various tasks.  It looks something like the following.

```
Employee    | Task   | 10/03/10 | 10/10/10 | 10/17/10 | 10/24/10 | ... | 12/26/11
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Doe, John   | Code   |      16  |      16  |       20 |       20 | ... |       40
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smith, Jane | Code   |      32  |      32  |       16 |       32 | ... |       32
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Doe, John   | Test   |      24  |      24  |       20 |       20 | ... |        0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smith, Jane | Test   |       0  |       0  |       16 |        0 | ... |        0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smith, Jane | QA     |       8  |       8  |        8 |        8 | ... |        8      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               TOTAL |      80  |      80  |       80 |       80 | ... |       80
```

Note that there are fifteen months of data on the sheet and that employee allocations are entered for each week of those fifteen months.  Currently, at the end of the fifteen months, a new sheet is created, but the database should maintain this data for historical purposes.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to create an editable form/datasheet that has the same look and feel?  If not, how about an alternative solution that still provides the user a quick glance at all fifteen months and allows easy editing of the data?  What would the back-end tables look like for your proposed solution?

Comment: You'd be better of getting away from the concept of trying to replicated the Excel UI in Access. It's never going to work well, and you're just hampering your ability to build an easy-to-use, easy-to-maintain, and fast application for your users. In other words, the goal of replicating Excel is badly misguided, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic de-normalization problem.

To produce an editable spread-sheet like view of your database you'll need a table with 66 columns (the two identifying columns and 64 weekly integer columns).  The question is whether you want the permanent storage of the data to use this table, or to use a normalized table with four columns (the two identifiers, the week-starting date, and the integer hours value).

I would give serious consideration to storing the data in the normalized form, then converting (using a temporary table) into the denormalized form, allowing the user to print/edit the data, and then converting back to normal form.

Using this technique you get the following benefits:

1. The ability to support rolling windows into the data (with 66 columns, you will see a specified 15 month period, and no other).  With a rolling window you can show them last month and the next 14 months, or whatever.
2. It will be substantially easier to do things like check peoples total hours per month, or compare the hours spent in testing vs QA for an arbitrary range of dates.

Of course, you have to write the code to translate between normal and denormal form, but that should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is one solution that I have explored a bit and I completely agree with the arguments for using a normalized table.  Translating this into the de-normalized view is where I have struggled with this approach. Basing a datasheet on a query makes for a long and  ugly query and produces a non-editable data sheet. Are you suggesting populating and reading a form using VBA?  If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: I am suggesting populating a temporary table using VBA, then basing the form on the table.  There are a number of different approaches you could take depending on whether each user has their own front-end database, whether you need to support multiple writers, and so on.  But essentially your VBA would take a starting date (D) and number (N) of weeks to show, create a table with the necessary number of columns and then loop N times, each time incrementing D by one week and using INSERT and UPDATE to transfer the normalized records into the appropriate temporary table column.

Comment: For more information on normalizing/de-normalizing tables, see the "Access 2007 VBA Bible," Chapter 11.